# Match two arrays with jquery and add an attribute to the matching between value and data-attribute

Tags: jquery, match, custom-data-attribute

Try to find a data-value in an array in a selected option with jquery, and when find it, I want to add an attribute, since they're an option tag, a selected attribute.

It seems pretty easy but actually it is not.

My code is the following:

```
function selected_element() {

            var association = $("#association").children("option").map(function() {
                return this.value;
            }).get();

            var ass_val =  $("#association").children("option");

            console.log(ass_val, association);

            var ass_data = $("#association").children("option").attr('data-selected');

            console.log(ass_data );

            if (ass_val == ass_data) {
                $("#association").children("option").val(ass_data).attr("selected","selected");
            }



        };
        selected_element();
```

This is just an example:

My first line will map my array, so I return the value (1,2,3,4).

My second line will return both options and values, but I can't do really a lot with them.

My ass_data is actually the array that I'm using to retrieve the data tag in this case (data-selected).

My last line of code is just an example of what I wish to achieve:

```
if (ass_val == ass_data) {
                    $("#association").children("option").val(ass_data).attr("selected","selected");
                }



            };
```

It won't work, is just to display my idea.

Comment: Your wording is hard to understand - so select an option from a dropdown, and for the selected option, look for a custom data-attribute, and if you find it, add another custom data attribute that you have set, right?

Comment: Exactly what I'm looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the values are unique you could just add an event listener for the dropdown and then `find()` the [:selected](https://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/) `option`:

```
$("#association").on("change", function () {
    var t   = $(this),
        val = t.val();

        if (val) { // filter out empty/null values as possible matches
             t.find(":selected").attr({<put attribute name here> : <attribute value here>});

             // for example
             // t.find(":selected").attr({"data-selected" : true});

        }
});
```